# PHP Ajax parsing the incorrect href

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've inherited a legacy CMS.

The articles at the top are parsing the correct url

https://www.tptg.co.uk/news

But when you click more articles at the bottom of the page ajax is pulling through the incorrect href ( /blog/id/post-name instead of the correct and working /

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">

    <button id="load-more" class="btn btn-primary center-block more-news-btn">
            more articles
        </button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#load-more").click(function() {

            var ids = new Array();
            $("article").each(function(i, o) {

                var id = $(o).data("blog-id");
                ids.push(id);
            });

            ids = JSON.stringify(ids);

            var searchTerm = $("input[name='searchTerm']").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?="https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"?>',
                context: document.body,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    excludeIDs: ids,
                    blockID: "blog_listing",
                    searchTerm: searchTerm
                }
            }).done(function(data) {

                // if the response ends in last tag then remove the load more button
                if (data.substr(data.length - 8) == '<last />')
                    target.hide();

                $('#article-col').append(data);

            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

Earlier in the template file (for the blog listing page) there is the array of the working posts which looks like this

```
<div id="blog-article-wrapper">
    <?php if( count( $articles ) > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 blog-columns" id="article-col">
        <?php foreach( $articles as $i => $article ): ?>

        <?php require( dirname(__FILE__)."/puredata_article.php"); //this is the actual article template thats shared between normal page loads and ajax requests   ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="text-xs-center p-x-2 p-y-2">
        No news to display
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">

        <button id="load-more" class="btn btn-primary center-block more-news-btn">
                    more articles
                </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the file mentioned there is

```
   <?php
    use Fluid\Ignite4\Config;
    use \IgniteApp\viewHelpers\PageViewHelper;
    ?>

    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <article class="m-b-1 blog-post" data-blog-id="<?= $article->getPrimaryKeyValue() ?>">

            <?php if( $article->hasImage() ): ?>

            <a href="<?= PageViewHelper::url($blogPage , $article , false ) ?>">
                <?=  $article->getImage()->setClasses("img-fluid blog-image") ?>
            </a>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <h1 class="p-x-3 p-t-2 p-b-1" style="line-height: 0.8em !important;">
                <a href="<?= PageViewHelper::url($blogPage , $article , false ) ?>">
                    <?= $article->title ?>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <p class="teaser p-x-3 p-b-1">
                <?= $article->teasercontent ?>
            </p>

            <hr>
            <div class="wide-article-footer clearfix p-x-3 p-b-1">

                <?php if( $article->getPublisher()->hasImage() ):?>

                <div class="publisher-image pull-left">
                    <a href="<?= PageViewHelper::url( $blogListingPage , false , false , array( " author " => $article->getPublisher()->getPrimaryKeyValue() )) ?>">
                        <?= $article->getPublisher()->getImage()->setClasses("img-fluid") ?>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="pull-left p-l-2 p-t-2 p-b-2">

                    <p>
                        <a style="color: #1A1A1A; font-weight: 500;" href="<?= PageViewHelper::url( $blogListingPage , false , false , array( " author " => $article->getPublisher()->getPrimaryKeyValue() )) ?>">Posted by
                          <?= $article->getPublisher()->user ?>
                      </a></br>
                        <?= $article->getCreated()->format("F j, Y") ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right share-wrapper clearfix">
                    <?php /*
                  <div class="share-text visible">
                      <p>
                          <a class="share-text-link">
                              <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> SHARE
                          </a>
                      </p>
                  </div>  */ ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end wide article footer -->

        </article>
    </div>
```

Please help I'm really stuck with this one I've project searched for the /blog/ and /view-article/ permalink and in the database only the id and post names are specified.

Comment: Can you please rephrase _“ajax is pulling through the incorrect href”_ in a way that actually makes some sense? I have no idea what you even mean by “pulling through” here. The button obviously works, it loads new posts. So what exactly is wrong and where …?

Comment: Hi @CBroe if you hover over the articles (to see the href) it loads they have a different permalink /blog/id/post instead of the correct /view-article/id/post and the incorrect link also goes to an incorrect template.